# Batch inserting with RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

Testing out RethinkDB and wanted to know the correct way to bath insert 1m rows using JavaScript client. Currently doing something like the following, but either simply stops inserting with no error or get a memory exception:

```
            for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
                r.table('people').insert({"name": i}).run(conn, function(err, result){
                    if(err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                });
            }
```

What's the best way to achieve this given the async nature of JS?

Comment: Rather look at the import function in the cli

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can batch your insert by passing an array of documents to insert `insert([doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4])`

You can also use multiple connections, and have one query at most run per connection -- you may be interested in the rethinkdbdash package if you don't want to manually do that (it provides a connection pool).

Comment: I see the optimum array size is 200 items. I want to load like 5 to 10m :-)

Comment: The optimum size depends on the size of your documents, your server etc. You need to experiment a bit. Using multiple connections would definitively show a huge improvement too.